# Preventing whitespaces between sections after using \linespread{2}

Tags: spacing, sectioning, line-spacing

I'm working on my thesis and there is something rather strange going on in terms of whitespacing. All is well if I do not use the linespread command.

However, as soon as I do use it, sections seem to be pushed to the next page and that creates a massive whitespace between different sections.

See the image below:

[image: screenshot of document]

All is okay on the first page, but then on page 2 there is a massive whitespace, presumably because LaTeX pushed the next section (1.2.1) to the next page.

Now I don't know enough of the terminology and thus probably have not exhausted my search, but I've tried setting parskip and that didn't work. This is using a standard template without any packages loaded. I'm using the 'book' template - for some reason when I use the 'article' template the spacing seems fine.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your linespread causes everything to take more vertical space.  If that subsection were to begin on page 2, it would be only the heading and likely not even a single line of text.  This is quite ugly from a layout point of view, so LaTeX prevents it.

Linespread is just for draft versions anyway, so I would not fret about this.  The images you show do not look bad.

Comment: Unfortunately, some institutions *require* double-spaced documents. There's nothing much that can be done in cases such like that, which may happen also with tight spacing when a section title has to be pushed on the next page (but the excess vertical space in the current page would not be as dramatic, probably).